# Saving hasMany relation in add form in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.4

I have a `Shop` that can have many `Offers` and I would like to create a new Shop and a number of Offers in the `add form` of the Shop.

From what I read the fields should look something like this

```
<?= $this->Form->control('offers.0.name', ['value' => 'awesome']); ?>
```

But I get a form error because the `shop_id` for the Offer is missing.

How do I structure my form to save the Shop and the Offers and cake fills in the newly created shop_id for the Offers.

Comment: Show Your `patchEntity()`

Comment: @kicaj so far I don't use patchEntity(). I was hoping I can solve this with the correct form structure.

Comment: If You wan save relation models You should use `patchEntity` with association params

Comment: According to cake naming convention, the primary key of tables should be "id". Post your Relation and table structure please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

//In Controller,

```
$shopTable=TableRegistry::get('Shop');
$entity = $shopTable->newEntity($this->request->getData(), [
           'associated' => [
                'Offers'
            ]
          ]);
```

OR, Same as patchEntity with associated ,you can do.